# Magento 2.4.3 - Product price change to 0.00 in product detail page

Tags: magento2.4

Product price show zero with currency place in product details when i upgrade magento version 2.4.2 to 2.4.3. I checked and found some js files issue. it depends on price-box.js, price-utils.js inside catalog core module and also depends on currency modal class in directory module

Answer (score 0):

it is fixed after upgrade version 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Magento 2.4.3, so you can fix it by applying the patch or upgrading to the latest version for security concerns.

Check this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856#issuecomment-904606945

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 2.4.3**

**Step:-1** Create di.xml **{vendore_name}/{module_name}/etc/di.xml** and add below code

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
            <plugin name="currency_format" type="{vendore_name}\{module_name}\Model\Currency" />
        </type>
       </config>
```

**Step:-2** Craete plugin file Currency.php **{vendore_name}/{module_name}/Model/Currency.php** and add below code

```
<?php
namespace {vendore_name}\{module_name}\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface;

class Currency
{
    /**
     * @var FormatInterface
     */
    private $localeFormat;
    /**
     * @var CurrencyInterface
     */
    private $localeCurrency;

    /**
     * Currency constructor.
     *
     * @param FormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
        FormatInterface $localeFormat

    ) {

        $this->localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
    }

    public function aroundFormatTxt(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        $price,
        $options = []
    ) {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }

        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        return $this->localeCurrency->getCurrency($subject->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }

}
```

**Step:-3** Run the below commands and check.
**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**